# How I can initialize CastleActiveRecord in WCF Service?

Tags: wcf, castle-activerecord

I need to initialize CastleActiveRecord in WCF service. How I can do it?

Answer (score 1):

http://www.darkside.co.za/archive/2010/07/16/initialise-castle-activerecord-was-wcf.aspx